# Understanding CMake variable behavior in SET() and MESSAGE() commands

Tags: variables, cmake, command

I am trying to understand CMake and have worked with some statements requiring me to comprehend the behavior of SET() and MESSAGE(). I worked out the following in Terminal and the results leave me puzzled:

```
➜  ~  cmake -P /dev/stdin
set(STATUS 5)
message(${STATUS} STATUS)
5STATUS

➜  ~  cmake -P /dev/stdin
set(STATUS 5)
message(STATUS ${STATUS})
-- 5
```

My questions are:

1. I've realized that `STATUS` itself is like a variable because it by default seems to print a line of `--` before any string that comes after it (try executing this statement `MESSSAGE( STATUS "Setting flags for GNU GCC")` and you will see what I mean). `STATUS` just will not work if I had put it in lower case `status` inside the `MESSAGE()` command. Similarly, we have the `FATAL_ERROR` variable which gives us a statement like `CMake Error at /foo/bar.c:2 (MESSAGE)`. It seems like `STATUS` and `FATAL_ERROR` are variables with pre-determined values. However, I have never seen any documentation for them, yet I have seen that other variables like `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` and `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` are documented, with their definitions being explained in books like Mastering CMake. Does anyone know where I can get a comprehensive listing and definition of all such variables like `STATUS` and `FATAL_ERROR`?
2. I do not understand the behavior that I saw on Terminal. Why is it that in the first case, having `STATUS` after `${STATUS}` gave me the word `STATUS` itself, while in the second case, with the order being reversed, `STATUS` before `${STATUS}` gave its original value of `--`?
3. For commands like `MESSAGE()` and `SET()` I've read from http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Language_Syntax that they are case insensitive. However, it this also the same for variables?

Thank you very much everyone and I will appreciate any feedback or comments to correct my misconceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[message command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/message.html). Also note the following:
1.- Using like this:

```
set(STATUS 5)
message(${STATUS} STATUS)
```

Is like passing *none* (see link to documentation) as first parameter to **message**. Meaning that you'll get a clean **5 status** on screen. 
2.-Using like this:

```
set(STATUS 5)
message(STATUS ${STATUS})
```

you are actually passing STATUS as the first parameter (again, see documentation about message) and as ${STATUS} is set to 5, you'll get only 5 on screen.

Comment: The first parameter has to be uppercase as well otherwise cmake will interpret it as part of the message rather than a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

See cmake --help-command message
or the documentation at cmake.org

The STATUS and FATAL_ERROR are not variables but function arguments. And yes, they are case sensitive. And yes, it's all documented. And yes, argument order matters.